# Is there any problem with using wine program loader?

Tags: wine

I want to use wine program loader, is there any problem in doing so?

Comment: Some apps work, other don't. If you want a more specific answer you'll have to give a more specific problem I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per se the wine program loader by itself installs well on all the Ubuntus since 8.04 (my first Ubuntu). For specific programs written to run on Microsoft Windows operating system, there may be work-arounds required to get them properly running on a Linux system under WinE. winehq website (https://appdb.winehq.org/) maintains a database of what works, and if it doesn't, what can be done about it. Typically, I have had to replace / over-ride default dlls using the winecfg program. I suggest you check-out what winehq says about the specific software that you are trying to get working.

However, I agree with Graham that for most requirements, the Linux equivalents are just as good if not vastly better.

Answer (score 0):

Seems stable enough for me for the (very) few legacy Windows applications I need to use it for although others say that there can be issues with some of the weightier programs which may be best run in VMware.

Where there are Linux alternatives for the applications you wish to use, it may be best to follow that route, if you are able.

Comment: But some programs such as "Nero Platinum HD" , and IP connector are not loading.
Even , KM Player is not working , Is something wrong?